# RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)?

Tags: flutter, dart

i got a problem in this part

```
snapshot.data!.docs[0].data()['list']
```

but in visual studio no error notification appears in the problem section, how to fix it? did i miss something?

```
StreamBuilder(
                            stream:
                                _firestore.collection("utils").snapshots(),
                            builder: (
                              BuildContext context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<
                                      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                                  snapshot,
                            ) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                final List<dynamic> _productGroups =
                                    snapshot.data!.docs[0].data()['list']
                                        as List<dynamic>;
                                _productGroups.sort();
                                return GridView.builder(
                                  gridDelegate:
                                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                                    childAspectRatio: 2,
                                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                                  ),
                                  itemCount: _productGroups.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return ProductGroupCard(
                                      name: _productGroups[index] as String,
                                      key: UniqueKey(),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              } else {
                                return const Center(
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    height: 40,
                                    width: 40,
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                      color: ColorPalette.pacificBlue,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: i think you have 0 docs. you need to check if snapshot.data.docs isnotempty

Comment: I think that if you create data directly from the firestore, the data will not be empty

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream:
              _firestore.collection("utils").snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<
                      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                  snapshot,) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(),
                  );
                }
                return GridView(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                  ),
                children:  snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  return Container(
                   // child: widget data['list']
                  );
                }).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: this fixed the error, but the data to be input becomes an error